# Mean per group and range

Tags: r

I could not understand how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me to sort out the problem.

I have data.frame like below

```
Gender  Age  BMI
Male     20  18
Male     40  22
Female   30  19
Male     50  24
Female   28  21
```

I would like to get the data.frame like following

```
Age Range  Male-BMI-Average  Female-BMI-Average
0-25        ###                  ###
26-50       ###                  ###
```

I tried to use cut and dcast but I could not understand how to get mean of different gender group within age range?

Comment: The shortest way is: you expose your efforts and possible errors and SO will suggest something if needed.

Comment: I could solve the problem in following way.

Step1: Subset MaleData
Step2: use CUT on MaleData
Step3: Aggregate on BMI of MaleData
Step4: Repeat step1- step3 on FemaleData
Step5: Marge them in one DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the 'AgeRange' and then with `dcast` from `data.table` convert it to 'wide' format and this is more easy in `data.table` as `dcast` have the `fun.aggregate` (here we specify it as `mean`).

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, AgeRange := cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 25, 50), 
                labels = c("0-25", "26-50"))], 
                AgeRange~Gender, value.var = "BMI", mean)
#   AgeRange Female Male
#1:   0-25    NaN   18
#2:  26-50     20   23
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can group by the `cut` created 'AgeRange' and just `summarise` with the `mean` of 'BMI' that corresponds to 'Male' and 'Female' in the 'Gender' column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(AgeRange = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 25, 50), 
                       labels = c("0-25", "26-50"))) %>%
    summarise(Male_BMI_Avg = mean(BMI[Gender=="Male"]), 
              Female_BMI_Avg = mean(BMI[Gender=="Female"]))
#  AgeRange Male_BMI_Avg Female_BMI_Avg
#    <fctr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#1     0-25           18            NaN
#2    26-50           23             20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using dplyr and reshape2 packages:

```
#Your Data
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, text="Gender  Age  BMI
Male     20  18
               Male     40  22
               Female   30  19
               Male     50  24
               Female   28  21")


library(dplyr)
results<-summarize(group_by(df, Gender, cut(df$Age, breaks=c(0, 25, 50))), mean(BMI))
library(reshape2)
names(results)<-c("Gender", "Age", "mean-BMI")
dcast(results, Age~Gender)
```